# Any basic CRUD for webapp2?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, crud

I'm trying to make a simple CMS on GAE, but could not find any up-to-date CRUD code example that uses ndb. The webapp2 docs where not enough for me to make one. So I appreciate if you could point me to a simple working example of CRUD to integrate into my simple CMS app.